# Test if button selected based

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to locate a button , which may or may not be selected.

I first find the xpath to the button, check is its selected, it is failing in this check   "Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"input"}"

What should my boolean line check be ?

```
  WebElement element =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[contains(@class,'i-icon--plus-18-movie')]"));

    boolean isChecked = element.findElement(By.tagName("input")).isSelected();
        if(isChecked){
            System.out.println("is checked");
                 element.click();
        }  


<age-question-button class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" state="qc.answer[question.name]" icon="plus-18-movie" active-text="The Customer is over 18" inactive-text="The Customer is NOT over 18" ng-repeat="question in qc.questionsList track by question.name" audit="cc.utils.audit(qc.answer[question.name] ? question.auditInactive : question.auditActive)">
<label class="c-option u-p-0 u-ml-md u-pull-left" tooltip-append-to-body="true" uib-tooltip="The Customer is NOT over 18">
<input class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ng-model="state" ng-change="audit()" style="" type="checkbox">
<i class="c-option__button i-icon i-icon--plus-18-movie"></i>
</label>
</age-question-button>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why is my check failing .. 

what should i be checking...

Comment: Please add html portion of the element you want to work with.

Comment: html added above.

Comment: Please use the below code and let me know your result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to avoid multiple class in same path.
You can use like below

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.className("ng-isolate-scope"));
WebElement element =  elem.findElement(By.className("ng-valid-parse"));

boolean isChecked = element.findElement(By.tagName("input")).isSelected();
if(isChecked){
    System.out.println("is checked");
    element.click();
}
```

IF you have multiple classes with same name you can use list and desired Index of that element.

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.className("ng-isolate-scope"));
List<WebElement> element =  elem.findElements(By.className("ng-valid-parse"));

boolean isChecked = element.get(indexOfyourdesiredELement).findElement(By.tagName("input")).isSelected();
if(isChecked){
       System.out.println("is checked");
       element.get(indexOfyourdesiredELement).click();
}
```

You can also write like

```
boolean isChecked =  element.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']")).isSelected();
```

**EDIT:** Here is the updated solution . It will click on the checkbox if it is checked. You can reverse the logic by yourself.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("age-question-button"));
boolean isChecked =  element.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']")).isSelected();
if(isChecked){
    System.out.println("is checked");
    element.click();
}
```

If multiple age-question-button question are there follow this.

```
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.tagName("age-question-button"));

    for(int i = 0 ; i< element.size() ; i++){
        boolean isChecked =  element.get(i).findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']")).isSelected();
        if(isChecked){
              System.out.println("is checked and it will click on checkbox if it is checked");

               element.get(i).click();
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Whats up with all the indentations? It makes the code difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: This looks like it will be the solution...

what would you recommend to be the best way to get 'indexOfyourdesiredELement"

Comment: Example : if there are 5 classes named "ng-valid-parse" and  you want to click the third checkbox then your index is 2 and if your desired checkbox is first one then use index 0. Index starts from zero(0). let me know your feedback

Comment: I have tried : 'boolean isChecked = element.get(0).findElement(By.tagName("input")).isSelected();'
and : 'boolean isChecked =  element.get(0).findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']")).isSelected();'

both fail as i get a 'java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0'  as no elements have been found.

Comment: WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.className("ng-isolate-scope"));
List<WebElement> element =  elem.findElements(By.className("ng-valid-parse"));

boolean isChecked = element.get(0).findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='check‌​box']")).isSelected(‌​);
if(isChecked){
       System.out.println("is checked");
       element.get(0).click();
}

Comment: still returning 0 results  ?

Comment: Okay just give me few more minutes. I am almost close to  your solution.

Comment: What do you want if the checkbox is checked you want to click? i got your solution

Comment: i have to run various tests , some are with it checked and some with it unchecked. All I will need to know whether it is checked , so the script can either click or not. Thanks

Comment: The above edit portion code solution worked for me in my local pc. Please try this and know me the result.

Comment: Cheers happy to know from you that finally it solved.

Comment: You can upvote this solution so that others can find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try using cssSelector `input[type='checkbox']`

```
WebElement element =  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']"));
boolean isChecked = element.isSelected();
    if(isChecked){
        System.out.println("is checked");
             element.click();
    }
```